# Mojarra vs MyFaces: empty attributes for html elements

Tags: html, jsf-2, myfaces, mojarra

Mojarra (2.1.x) removes an empty attribute, while MyFaces keeps them. Is there anyway to have MyFaces also remove an empty attribute from html element? For example if you have `<input disabled="" />`, Mojarra outputs it as `<input />` and while MyFaces outputs it as `<input disabled="" />`.

I couldn't find [any matching config key](https://myfaces.apache.org/core22/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html) for my need.

**UPDATE 1**
I need this in order to implement my custom non-JSF [select2 element](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) (which is manually filled from a JSF bean). I have a `<ui:repeat>` over a set of `<select>`s, and I want to set it's `disabled` or `selected` attribute in a single EL expression. With this nice bug in Mojarra a select like this: `<select name="n" value="v" selected="#{false}" disabled="#{false}" />` is outputed as `<select name="n" value="v" />`.

Comment: Why should such attributes be removed? That would change the meaning of the HTML element. The `disabled` attribute sets the element to disabled state (no matter what the attribute value is). And e.g. `alt=""` is different from lack of an `alt` attribute.

Comment: Just clarified in my question why I need such a thing.

Comment: The original question asks how to make some software remove attributes with empty values. The update asks how to prevent removal, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: I actually want to make MyFaces remove empty attributes. Also in update I mentioned the **nice** Mojarra bug (which I've written some code based on it already) which removes selected="" and disabled="" from the output.